# RequireJS dependency sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs

I have this plugin that requires jQuery. I won't use the jQuery version of require for certain reasons not related.

```
define(['jquery','dep1','dep2','mymodule'],function($,foo,bar,plugin){
    //all loaded
});
```

Due to the nature of AMD loaders, order is not guaranteed. The [order plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#order) also states that the plugin is not to be used with define calls, thus, module definitions. And [the API](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep) only guarantees the order of arguments, not the order of execution. So if there is an incident where mymodule loads before jQuery, it will fail.

How do I guarantee loading of required dependencies before plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it doesn't look like you are using the order plugin; the order plugin needs you to prepend `order!` to the file name.

Second, your `mymodule` file should also have define `jQuery` as a requirement. That will ensure that jquery is loaded before mymodule without having to depend on the order plugin.

**Module 1**

```
define(['jquery','dep1','dep2','mymodule'],function($,foo,bar,plugin){
    //all loaded
});
```

**mymodule.js**

```
define(['jquery'],function($){
    //all loaded
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
define(['jquery', 'dep1', 'dep2'], function() {
    //load myModule separately
    var m = require('mymodule');
});
```